# Mapping by Object Key Returns 0?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, object, key

I am updating a state to get all the keys from an object called ""types" in separate buttons, but I only got a 0:

```
{Object.keys(types).map((key) => <button>{key}</button>)}
```

Or all the keys in the same button:

```
{types.map(types=> <button>{Object.keys(types)}</button>)}
```

Why?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a complete example with expected output

Comment: What does `types` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` function is applied for arrays.
`Object.keys(types)` is an array of keys of types.
For example, let's imagine that types is given as follow

```
types = {key1: 1, key2: 2}
```

In this case

```
Object.keys(types) = ["key1", "key2"]
Object.keys(types).map // equals ["key1", "key2"].map
types.map // equals {key1: 1, key2: 2}.map
```

See the difference.